# Get Constant variable name from value

Tags: ruby, constants

I have a class called `Source` with some constants eg:

```
def Source
  INTERNET = 0
  BOOK = 1
  etc...
end
```

I know how to retrieve the value of a constant by doing `Source.constants("BOOK")` which will return `1`.

However is it possible to do the reverse? So retrieve the constant name from the value?
e.g.
`Source.constants(1)` returns `BOOK`

Comment: This is where a structure like `{ internet: 0, book: 1 }` is often a better call. What problem are you trying to solve here? With a little metaprogramming this can be solved in a consistent way, like `Source.internet` or `Source.with_name("internet")` or even `Source["INTERNET"]` depending on the ergonomic concerns.

Comment: Is your question sparked from curiosity or do you have an actual need for an answer? I can't imagine it being the latter.

Comment: FYI you should be using `Source::BOOK` in most cases, not `Source.constants("BOOK")`, unless you specifically have a string containing an unknown constant name.

Comment: I realize several people have mentioned this, but this is the wrong solution for whatever problem you have. You should not use constants in a class to map names to numbers, you should use a hash for this. A class further up the inheritance hierarchy may introduce constants that you didn't mean to make accessible, the solution offered below has an O(N) lookup time, and the ergonomics are terrible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do as following:

```
class Source
  INTERNET = 0
  BOOK = 1
end

# Retrieve the constant name from the value
constant_name = Source.constants.find { |c| Source.const_get(c) == 1 }

puts constant_name # Output: BOOK
```

However, it's better to have a method to find the constant from a value like:

```
module Source
  INTERNET = 0
  BOOK = 1
  # define more enum values here...

  def self.from_value(value)
    case value
    when INTERNET
      :INTERNET
    when BOOK
      :BOOK
    # map more values to their respective symbols here...
    else
      raise ArgumentError, "Invalid Source value: #{value}"
    end
  end
end


source = Source::BOOK
puts source # Output: 1

source_name = Source.from_value(1)
puts source_name # Output: :BOOK
```